# How can I store string data into individual arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, xml, sorting

I am extracting data from an xml file :

```
import numpy as np 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from lxml import etree

data = '/Users/hudaiftikhar/Desktop/eis-modelling/ISEAFramework-master/scenarios/electrical/tesla.xml'

SOC = []
My_Res=[]

doc = etree.parse(data.encode())
print(doc,'doc')

soc = doc.xpath('//CustomDefinitions//MyRser[@class="OhmicResistance"]//MeasurementPointsRow[@ desc="StateOfCharge"]/text()')
for val in soc:
    SOC.append(val)
    SOC_ = [x.replace('\n\t\t\t\t', '') for x in SOC]

myRes_lud = doc.xpath('//CustomDefinitions//MyRser[@class="OhmicResistance"]//LookupData/text()')
for vals in myRes_lud:
    My_Res.append(vals)
    Res_ = [x.replace('\n\t\t\t\t\t' , '') for x in My_Res]
    Res_update= [x.replace(';\n\t\t\t\t' , '') for x in Res_]


print('soc',SOC_)
print('res',Res_update)
```

The output I get is :

```
soc ['-5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105']
res ['0.02597518381655694900, 0.02513715386193249600, 0.02394715132636577100, 0.02325996676357371800, 0.02317075771456176400, 0.02277814077034603900, 0.02267913709322775700, 0.02258569292134297900, 0.02235026503875497600, 0.02222478423822949300, 0.02207606555239715500, 0.02198493491067361700, 0.02188144525929673300, 0.02167985791309091600, 0.02145797158835977700, 0.02137484908165417400, 0.02126561803424023600, 0.02124462299304301700, 0.02123310358079429400, 0.02126287857906075300, 0.02094998489960795500, 0.02073326148328196600, 0.02062489977511897100, 0.02038933084432985300']
```

But this is being stored as a string on the index 0 of the array, I want to have an array for soc and res that stores each value individually as float , not as a single string. It would be a great help if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `split()`

Like this:

```
SOC_ = ['-5, 0, 7.100000e+00, 1.120000e+01, 16, 2.080000e+01, 2.560000e+01, 3.040000e+01, 3.520000e+01, 4.010000e+01, 4.490000e+01, 4.970000e+01, 5.450000e+01, 5.930000e+01, 6.420000e+01, 69, 7.380000e+01, 7.860000e+01, 8.350000e+01, 8.830000e+01, 9.310000e+01, 9.770000e+01, 100, 105']

list_of_soc = SOC_[0].split(",")  # splits the first position of the array by the delimiter ","

print(list_of_soc)
```

This prints:

```
['-5', ' 0', ' 7.100000e+00', ' 1.120000e+01', ' 16', ' 2.080000e+01', ' 2.560000e+01', ' 3.040000e+01', ' 3.520000e+01', ' 4.010000e+01', ' 4.490000e+01', ' 4.970000e+01', ' 5.450000e+01', ' 5.930000e+01', ' 6.420000e+01', ' 69', ' 7.380000e+01', ' 7.860000e+01', ' 8.350000e+01', ' 8.830000e+01', ' 9.310000e+01', ' 9.770000e+01', ' 100', ' 105']
```

Applied to your code at the print statement you can just do this

```
print('soc',SOC_[0].split(";"))
print('res',Res_update[0].split(";"))
```

For the float you should be able to simply use `float()` like this

```
SOC_ = [float(x.replace('\n\t\t\t\t', '') for x in SOC)]

Res_update= [float(x.replace(';\n\t\t\t\t' , '') for x in Res_)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the raw XML, there is a possible addition to your code: If you're comfortable using list comprehensions, then you can split the string by commas and cast the results as floats using the following statements

```
SOC_result = [float(number) for number in SOC_.split(", ")]

Res_update_result = [float(number) for number in Res_update.split(", ")]
```

This processes the SOC variable like so

```
[-5.0, 0.0, 7.1, 11.2, 16.0, 20.8, 25.6, 30.4, 35.2, 40.1, 44.9, 49.7, 54.5, 59.3, 64.2, 69.0, 73.8, 78.6, 83.5, 88.3, 93.1, 97.7, 100.0, 105.0]
```